# Handlebars wraps <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, templating, metalsmith

I am trying to get my `metalsmith` setup working, nothing fancy.

In my `build.js` I have:

```
…
handlebars.registerHelper('doctype', function() {
  return new handlebars.SafeString('<!DOCTYPE html>');
});
…
```

in my partial template `header.hbt` I have:

```
{{doctype}}
<html>
…
```

And the result html begins with:

`<p>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</p>`

– which is obviously not what I need.

Any suggestions?

PS. Using a plain doctype definition in my layout file had the same effect. Using `handlebars ^4.0.5`.

**Edit 1:**
After trying around a bit, i can supply another symptom: The result of a `SafeString()` call seems to be wrapped in a `<p>` tag if it is placed before the `<html>` block. This is not specific to the doctype declaration, »normal« html elements seem to be affected as well.

**Edit 2:**
Now i have distilled 2x2 cases for the functioning of `safeString()`:

a) a *conventional* element (e.g. `<div>`) inside the `<html>` block gets rendered, as expected, without changes.

b) a *conventional* element before the `<html>` block gets rendered ok, but is placed inside a `<p>` tag.

c) a *doctype* element inside the `<html>` block gets rendered as pure text, like this: `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;`

d) a *doctype* element before the `<html>` block will be rendered in the same manner but wrapped in a `<p>` element.

Comment: guess what SafeString was made for

Comment: https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/blob/master/docs/helpers/html/helper-doctype.md

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your second comment!

Comment: well to explain the issue here: handlebars.SafeString will return a string that you can use -safely- inside html by threating it as text rather html

Comment: The suggested library looks promising, thanks! However, it doesn't seem trivial integrating it into my setup. Moreover, i would like to understand what is wrong with my code, since i have copy/pasted it from a documentation site.

Comment: @GottZ thanks for the insight! Yes, you are right, in order for html to render correctly it must be interpreted / copied as string. But in this case it escapes it, which is the role of the `escapeExpression()` function. I am still not sure, if it is a `handlebars` or `metalsmith` specific problem. Also, i couldn't get `handlebar-helpers` to work with my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a `metalsmith`-related matter, not inherent to `handlebars`. A given *(erroneous!)* order of plugin invocations causes the issue: calling `use(layouts(…))` before calling `use(markdown(…))` is the cause. (so probably the `markdown` plugin does the wrapping.) Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Which plugin was causing this? Would be nice to know for others that have the problem.

Comment: @ismay: Sorry for the delay, just edited the answer.